# Thymeleaf Template Engine - Error cannot use Preprocessing Expression (__${expression}__)

Tags: java, kotlin, thymeleaf, template-engine

I got this kind of error when I tried to use the Preprocessing expression?
Does anyone know how to allow the Preprocessing Expression to be usable in Thymeleaf Template Engine?

I think I might have missed some configurations with the template engine that's why it threw this error.

Are there any configurations that need to be added in order to make it work? or any workaround?

Here is the sample HTML and Thymeleaf codes that I was trying to use:

```
<li class="list-item" th:each="item : ${data.getApps(__${ids}__)}">
    <a th:text="${item.appName}">App Name</a>
</li>
```

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [data.getApps(__${ids}__)] @27: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual code that causes the error. Without it, we cannot say where or why the problem is happening.

Comment: @SeverityOne I've added the code, please have a look at it. Actually, I think that this code was fine, but there might be some problems that I'm not aware of on the backend side.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have the underlying bean from which the data is fetched, but you're putting business logic in your presentation logic, which is never a good idea. `${ids}` is some sort of variable coming from the bean, so I'd create a method `getApps()` that looks like the following:

```
public Collection<App> getApps() {
    return getData(getIds());
}
```

and then change your Thymeleaf template as follows:

```
<li class="list-item" th:each="item: ${apps}">
    <a th:text="${item.appName}">App Name</a>
</li>
```

Please note that I have to guess what the Java code looks like, so this is likely to be imprecise.